# Add a scrollTop value into a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

**Example link**: `example.com/cool.php?scroll=javaSriptScrollTopValue`

What I want to do is get the `var y = elmnt.scrollTop;` as the page is going up and down and put that value into the hyperlink and there are 10 links on the page?

I need the scrollTop value in the hyperlink for the next page to use.

How would I do that thanks!

Comment: You could set a query string on page via jquery and on your other page, get the query string parameters as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into query strings it sounds promising! As long as I can get the scrollTop to the next page that is what I need to do.